# Unable to display JSON object

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

The error that I'm getting is this if I use dataType:'json':

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

If I use `dataType:'html'` then I could see the array passed form php page in the console like this:

```
[{
    "type": ["4 wheeler", "flying car", "test type"],
    "maker": ["Honda", "Audi", "test car"],
    "rate": [
        ["0", "78"],
        ["0", "56"],
        ["0", "34"],
        ["2", "78"],
        ["2", "56"],
        ["2", "34"],
        ["1", "89"],
        ["1", "7"],
        ["1", "56"]
    ]
}]
```

In my php page, this is how I'm passing the multidimensional array.

```
$json=array();
array_push($json,array("type"=>$carType,"maker"=>$carMaker,"rate"=>$selectRate));
echo json_encode($json);
```

WHat is my mistake here? AM I not passign JSON object from this page? How do I access each element in each array via jquery in success function?

whole code for ajax

```
$("#submit").on("click",function()
    {

          $("#set_setting").submit(function(){            

            data = $(this).serialize()
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              dataType: "html",
              url: "submit_setting.php", //Relative or absolute path to response.php file
              data: data,
               success: function(data) {
                   //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                   //data=JSON.stringify(data);
                   console.log(data);
                     //hide the form
                     $("#set_setting").slideUp("slow");

                     //show the result


                      $.each( data.type, function( index, value ){
                           console.log(value);
                      });
                 }

            });
            return false;

          });

        });
```

Comment: The error you provide doesn't seem to match in your code. Can you share your whole code?

Comment: @LinkinTED i updated my post with the whole code

Comment: What does the console say? Or nothing? Then try adding the error event as well and see what error gets logged.

Comment: You might also try to add a content type to your PHP code: `header("Content-type: application/json");`. Put it before your echo.

Comment: And change the dataType in `$.ajax` to `json`

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the array across as plain text. It needs to be serialized to JSON. I don't know the syntax in php you'll need to look that up. You can test this by making the call from Postman or Fiddler and you'll see the response type.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add key like below i think!

```
$json['data']=array(); 
$json['data'] = array("type"=>$carType,"maker"=>$carMaker,"rate"=>$selectRate); 
echo json_encode($json);
```

please refer [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7Ba9T/) link for access json object and see result in browser console

Answer (score 0):

You already serialized the array in to json , So you can't access the array in html data type. You need to return the data as html for accessing it as html format in js.

Best practice is to print the array using print_r instead of echo . echo can't print the array elements in php.

```
 <?php print_r($json) ?>
```

Then use a foreach loop to loop the elements.

Comment: this works as its in the php page. But I'm havin gproblem passing this array to another page via ajax as json and display in for loop